# Macchanger returns error in the terminal

Tags: command-line

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. When I try to change my mac address using the `macchanger` on the terminal I get this error message:

```
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Operation not permitted
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

"Insufficient permissions" usually means you need to have root privileges. Try using `sudo`, e.g. `sudo macchanger <arguments>`.

If that doesn't work probably the other cause is true: "interface up". You have to turn the interface off before changing the MAC address. You can do it with `sudo ifconfig <interface name> down`, e.g. `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`. Then change the mac address. But after that remember to turn the interface on again with `sudo ifconfig <interface name> up`.